# After uploading a file to Drupal 7 via a form, how to get the file's path?

Tags: php, drupal, fileapi

I have a form that uploads a file to my Drupal installation. I want to store the path to that file in a table. How do I get the path to the recently uploaded file? I tried

```
$f = file_load($form_state['values']['field_file']);
$f->uri;
```

But that's not working. Any clues?

Comment: When you say not working, what exactly is happening?

Comment: Well, you see when I upload the file, it the #upload path is: public://images/. And that uploads it to a directory within the Drupal installation (/sites/default/files/images/). And then, to insert it into the database I use $f->uri. But when I pull it out of the database to display it, the img src is public://images/myimage.png - which is a broken link. My real question is how do I change that part so it displays correctly. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Ah, that's the standard D7 internal URL structure. You need to convert it to a usable URL with `file_create_url()`. Posted an answer stating this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$f = file_load($form_state['values']['field_file']);
$url = file_create_url($f->uri);
```

The URI is the public:// private:// etc which Drupal uses internally. To convert it use file_create_url(); Ideally you should still store the URI and then use the `file_create_url()` when rendering.

Comment: file_create_url provides the absolute url. Is there any way to obtain the relative url?

Comment: When you say relative- relative to what? the docroot or the `sites/default/files` folder? Look at [`file_build_uri`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_build_uri/7) for the former and [`file_uri_target`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_uri_target/7) for the latter

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug the $f object and see if some error happens:

```
$f = file_load($form_state['values']['field_file']);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($f);
```